# Add a column with an image of the invoice status Canceled or open c#

Tags: c#, image, loops, if-statement, datagridview

I want to put a cell in every row I have. If a cell that contains an invoice is open, I want to display a certain picture and if it is closed, I want to display another picture in that cell.

**Error picture:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
this.dgvBills.DataSource = bill.SearchBills(txtSearch.Text, coBoxState.Text);
                DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                img.Name = "img";
                img.HeaderText = "Image Column";
                img.ValuesAreIcons = true;
                dgvBills.Columns.Add(img);
                int number_of_rows = dgvBills.RowCount;
                for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
                {
                    if (dgvBills.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString() == "open")
                    {

                        dgvBills.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = pbox.Image;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        dgvBills.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = pbox.InitialImage;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this.  For a purely visual indicator like this icon, you may be better off displaying the icon during cell formatting.

Handle the DataGridView's `CellFormatting` event-

```
private void dgvBills_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    switch (dgvBills.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
        case "img": // The name of your image column 

            if (dgvBills.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString() == "open")
                e.Value = pbox.Image; // image stored in a PictureBox
            else
                e.Value = pbox.InitialImage; // image stored in a PictureBox

            break;
    }
}
```

You can clean this up further by changing your image source.  Ditch the PictureBox, and use your project Resources.  As an example, if you created two 16x16 PNG icons to represent open and closed states, you can add them to your project Resources as `open_invoice` and `closed_invoice`.

Then the value assignments become more readable in your code-

```
e.Value = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.open_invoice);
e.Value = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.closed_invoice);
```

Or if you need to set a "blank" icon-

```
e.Value = new Bitmap(1, 1);
```

If you have control over your Data Source, you can tidy this even further.  Let suppose that your `bill.SearchBills()` function returns `List<Bill>`.  Then you can design your `Bills` class to return a `Bitmap` directly as a class Property.

```
public class Bill
{
    public Image OpenClosedIcon
    {
        get
        {
            return IsOpen
                ? new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.open_invoice)
                : new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.closed_invoice);
        }
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // The rest of your Bill class definition... 

}
```

The advantage of this is data binding.  When the data source provides it, the DataGridView can recognize the Bitmap field and render it correctly in a DataGridViewImageColumn, without additional work from you.

The easiest approach is usually to use the DataGridView's built-in column designer, and create the columns you want.  For your DataGridViewImageColumn, set the `DataPropertyName` to your class field name `OpenClosedIcon`

With a fully-prepared data source, you likely won't need the CellFormatting handler at all.